# Find the lowest unused number in an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array full of numbers. Here's an example:

```
myArray = [0,1,2,4,5];
```

I need to find the lowest unused number starting from 1, so in this case it will be 3.

I've been reading up of using `indexOf` but I'm unsure how to use it for my specific purpose.

Comment: Is the array guaranteed to be sorted, as in your example?

Comment: iter on your array. find the first item that does not match the index.

Comment: @njzk2 this only works if the array is always sorted.

Comment: I would reconsider your design if this is required

Comment: Can the array start with any number like [23,24,26,27] and it will be 25 in this case?

Comment: No it's unordered and say if 3 was taken then it's needs to take the last number and then add 1. So in this case it would be 6.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the array isn't sorted, you always start at 0, and taking into account your desire to find a highest number if there isn't one missing:

```
var k = [6, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5];

k.sort(function(a, b) { return a-b; });   // To sort by numeric

var lowest = -1;
for (i = 0;  i < k.length;  ++i) {
  if (k[i] != i) {
    lowest = i;
    break;
  }
}
if (lowest == -1) {
    lowest = k[k.length - 1] + 1;
}
console.log("Lowest = " + lowest);
```

Logs answer 3.  If 3 was also in there, would log 7 since no other number is missing.

If you aren't always starting at zero, use an offset:

```
var k = [6, 2, 3, 4, 5];

k.sort(function(a, b) { return a-b; });   // To sort by numeric

var offset = k[0];
var lowest = -1;
for (i = 0;  i < k.length;  ++i) {
  if (k[i] != offset) {
    lowest = offset;
    break;
  }
  ++offset;
}
if (lowest == -1) {
    lowest = k[k.length - 1] + 1;
}
console.log("Lowest = " + lowest);
```

Logs answer 7 since none are missing after 2 which starts the sequence.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I would always need to check from 1 and it would be an unordered list. What would I need to do if there isn't a lowest number available and I would therefore need to take the highest number in the array and plus 1. So in my example it would be 6

Comment: Not sure what you mean about highest number in your example.  Do you mean if you had [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] you'd want 5 since there's no missing number?  I'll edit the code for that.

Comment: Yes exactly, yes please :)

Answer (score 2):

This takes a sequence starting from a number (like 1 in your example) and returns the lowest unused number in the sequence.

```
function lowestUnusedNumber(sequence, startingFrom) {
  const arr = sequence.slice(0);
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  return arr.reduce((lowest, num, i) => {
    const seqIndex = i + startingFrom;
    return num !== seqIndex && seqIndex < lowest ? seqIndex : lowest
  }, arr.length + startingFrom);
}
```

Example:

```
> lowestUnusedNumber([], 1)
1
> lowestUnusedNumber([1,2,4], 1)
3
> lowestUnusedNumber([3], 1)
1
```

In exchange for readability, it's slightly less optimized than the other example because it loops over all items in the array instead of breaking as soon as it finds the missing item.